# How do I automate\script exporting reports in facebook power editor?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have to login and export an ads report every day- how do I automate this?

I want have a script download a csv of a report to my computer every morning.

Can I use curl? Do I *have* to use the API? What options do I have for this?

Facebook can schedule emailing the report, but it doesn't actually email the report it just emails a link to the report.

Haven't been able to test this yet, but it looks like [this guy used to be able to use wget to pull a report](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=887599711347301) (but now it doesn't work)

Edit: I'm trying to do this with curl
Before I create an app id I am trying to just do this with a user token generated from the graph app and it does not appear to be working:

```
curl 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?MYREPORTNAME&format=csv&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN'
```

I see in the documentation examples using curl, how do I use curl to download a report?

Comment: Yes you have to use the API

Comment: To use the API it says I need to create a developer account and I need to create an app that's going to run on a web server. I just want to download a report not write an application.

Comment: Someone you need to authenticate that you are then one downloading it. That is done using apps.

Comment: Do I need to run a webserver and use the API or can I just generate a token and use curl? I'm confused because at the below link it shows three examples of accessing info the PHP or Python SDK or curl: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started/v2.5#marketing-api-quickstart

Comment: Curl is fine. You don't need a webserver

Comment: The access token expire, but it looks like I can generate them with a get request. So can I just generate access tokens with wget and then use those tokens to download reports?

Comment: You can't generate access token using wget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to the recently released tool **Facebook Ads Manager for Excel**. It allows you to refresh your reporting with one click.

Please see: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/229431170840352

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with FB API to try to automate the reports...

First with python generate the report with the fields I need, code:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adreportrun import AdReportRun
import time

my_app_id = 'your_app_id'
my_app_secret = 'your_app_secret'
my_access_token = 'you_access_token'

FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
campaign = Campaign(your_campaig_id)
campaign.remote_read(fields=[
    Campaign.Field.effective_status 
])

params = {
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.ad,
    'fields': [
        AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.account_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
        AdsInsights.Field.spend,
        AdsInsights.Field.unique_clicks,
        AdsInsights.Field.unique_inline_link_clicks,
        AdsInsights.Field.total_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.total_unique_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.unique_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.reach,
        AdsInsights.Field.video_p100_watched_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.video_p25_watched_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.video_p50_watched_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.video_p75_watched_actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.video_p95_watched_actions,                
    ],  
    'time_range': {'since':'2017-08-01','until':'2017-08-01'},
}

async_job = campaign.get_insights(params=params, async=True)
async_job.remote_read()
while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100:
    time.sleep(1)
    async_job.remote_read()    
time.sleep(1)

print(async_job.get_result())
print async_job.remote_read()
```

The last 'print' shows the report_id.

Then with CURL you need the report_id, and access_token to export locally, curl:

```
curl -G -d 'report_run_id=you_report_id' -d 'format=csv' 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?access_token=your_access_token' -o ReportCURL.csv
```

I Hope this helps!